# Does onEdit or onChange run when a GOOGLEFINANCE or time-based function updates?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a program in Google Apps Script for `Google Sheets` and have been having trouble finding descriptive documentation on the `onEdit` and `onChange` functions. I would like to know, are `onEdit` and `onChange` only triggered by user changes/edits or would an automated edit (e.g. a `GOOGLEFINANCE` or time-based function update) also trigger it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Only edits or changes made by a user are taken into account for the triggers. You'll have to find a way to call the desired function from the function that runs on a timer.

Comment: This is not directly related to you question, but I've had success with setting up a reload function similar to [here](https://gist.github.com/aGHz/6868a1ea1defbd6b9ed5)

Comment: [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) only fire when the user does something.

Comment: If the Google Sheets API is used to update values in a spreadsheet, it will trigger an On Change event, which will cause an installed On Change trigger to fire.  The Sheets API can be run from Apps Script.  Normally, you'd never do that, because you don't need the API to do things to the sheet.  You'd just use built-in services.  But if you want to trigger the On Change event, you can use the REST API to update the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@Sandy Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946873/sandy-good)

> If the Google Sheets API is used to update values in a spreadsheet, it will trigger an On Change event, which will cause an installed On Change trigger to fire. The Sheets API can be run from Apps Script. Normally, you'd never do that, because you don't need the API to do things to the sheet. You'd just use built-in services. But if you want to trigger the On Change event, you can use the REST API to update the spreadsheet.